# How to get the name of the render result image from a script

Tags: python, scripting

When you render anything in Blender, the output is sent to an image that is called (by default) "Render Result".

However, the user can change the name of that image, and any subsequent renders are then sent to that renamed image.

So, for a script that is doing some rendering, and then wants to get the result, it cannot be assumed that such result will be in an image called "Render Result".

How can I determine (from a script) the name of the image where the results from a render will reside?

Comment: Since the next step in a script would probably be saving the image, you could do both immediately: [bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=True)](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_70_5/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.render). That way the image is saved in the filepath location and you can read it from the filesystem whenever you need it.

Comment: @Leander Yeah, thank you, but I am aware of that. Later in the script I will want to save externally, and already have the code to do exactly that. Before that happens, however, I want to take an internal copy of the image for other purposes. I can't copy it if I can't "find" it, and I can't find it without knowing the name (at least as far as I am aware).

Comment: Maybe I wasnt very clear. I am suggesting that you immediately load it again, now that it is stored on your hard disk. `bpy.data.images.new(...` what other purposes do you want. Could you describe what you need the image for, before saving it?

Comment: @Leander Oh, I misunderstood what you meant. That is a good idea. It seems a bit overkill (as the image is already internal, I would prefer a way to simply "find" it internally rather than writing it out to the fs and reading it back in) but that is definitely a potential solution that I can experiment with. Thank you.

Also, I want to render a number of images and keep them internal. The user may or may not save the images externally, but they should always exist internally. This is why I was looking to take a copy of the "Render Result" image after each render (if that makes sense).